# How to JOIN three tables with IN array filter, but still get all the rows from third table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have Users and Skills table connected through UserSkills table for many-to-many relation. Here is what's in the tables:

```
Users (id, username)
Skills (id, name)
UserSkills (user_id, skill_id)
```

I have an array of skills that I am looking for ['C#', 'SQL']. So I am doing join with IN filtering operation to get only those users that I need.

```
SELECT (username, GROUP_CONCAT(Skills.name)) FROM Users
JOIN UserSkills ON Users.id = UserSkills.user_id
JOIN Skills ON Skills.id = UserSkills.skill_id AND Skills.name IN ('C#', 'SQL')
GROUP BY Users.id
```

I want to get same users list but with all their skills, not only those that I am looking for. For instance:

```
In my case I get: username: 'joe' | skills: 'C#', 'SQL'
I want to get: username: 'joe' | skills : 'C#', 'SQL', 'JavaScript', 'NodeJS'
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straight forward way would be to just join a second time:

```
SELECT u.username, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT userS.name)
FROM Users AS u
INNER JOIN UserSkills AS us ON u.id = us.user_id
INNER JOIN Skills AS filterS ON filterS.id = us.skill_id AND filterS.name IN ('C#', 'SQL')
INNER JOIN Skills AS userS ON userS.id = us.skill_id
GROUP BY u.id
```

But you will need the DISTINCT in GROUP_CONCAT as the filter skills will basically cross join with the user skills. Also worth noting is this query gets users with **any** of the skills specified not all. This is a better solution:

```
SELECT u.username, GROUP_CONCAT(s.name) AS skils
   , COUNT(CASE WHEN s.name IN ('C#', 'SQL') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS matchedSkillCount
FROM Users AS u
   INNER JOIN UserSkills AS us ON u.id = us.user_id
   INNER JOIN Skills AS s ON s.id = us.skill_id
GROUP BY u.id
HAVING matchedSkillCount > 0 -- You can replace 0 with the number of matches you want
;
```

...but on very large databases, the above might become costly; a couple other alternatives:

```
SELECT u.username, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT userS.name)
FROM Skills AS filterS 
INNER JOIN UserSkills AS ufs ON filterS.id = ufs.skill_id
INNER JOIN Users AS u ON ufs.user_id = u.id
INNER JOIN UserSkills AS us ON u.id = us.user_id
INNER JOIN Skills AS userS ON us.skill_id = userS.id
WHERE filterS.name IN ('C#', 'SQL')
GROUP BY u.id;

SELECT u.username, GROUP_CONCAT(s.name) AS skils       
FROM Users AS u
   INNER JOIN UserSkills AS us ON u.id = us.user_id
   INNER JOIN Skills AS sON s.id = us.skill_id
WHERE u.id IN (
   SELECT DISTINCT ufs.user_id
   FROM Skills AS filterS 
      INNER JOIN UserSkills AS ufs ON filterS.id = ufs.skill_id
   WHERE filterS.name IN ('C#', 'SQL')
)
GROUP BY u.id
;
```

*Logically, the WHERE is applied after the joins; but most RDBMS (like MySQL) optimize execution by using the WHERE conditions to minimize the rows joined together.*

Comment: Yeah, you are right, for MySql the first option is out, need to explicitly put WHERE at the end of the query.

Comment: First option should be just fine, just the need for DISTINCT it creates doesn't feel as "clean" to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
select USERS.name,GROUP_CONCAT(Skills.name) from USERS join USERSKILLS on users.id =
USERSKILLS.user_id join skills on USERSKILLS.SKILL_ID = skills.ID and  users.id in (
select distinct users.id from 
users join USERSKILLS on users.id = USERSKILLS.user_id join skills on skills.id = userSkills.skill_id and 
Skills.name IN ('C#', 'SQL'))
group by USERS.name;
```